# CIFS root permissions problem

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm having trouble accessing the root directory of another Linux machine. 
In my fstab I have two entries for the machine in question

```
//ltotto/root   /mnt/ltroot     cifs    auto,users,credentials=/home/otto/.smbcredentials,uid=otto,gid=otto,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//ltotto/otto   /mnt/ltotto     cifs    auto,users,credentials=/home/otto/.smbcredentials,uid=otto,gid=otto,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

i.e. both to the same machine with the same credentials. On the other machine there are two Samba shares 'root' and 'otto' for '/' and '/home/otto' respectively, both with write permission for the user otto.

Both are mounted with no errors and the 'otto' mount works perfectly. 
The 'root' mount however is the problem

```
ls -la /mnt/ltroot/
ls: /mnt/ltroot/var: Permission denied
ls: /mnt/ltroot/lib64: Permission denied
ls: /mnt/ltroot/cdrom: Permission denied
[etc]
```

I can't understand why the home mount is fine and the root mount not. Can anyone explain and suggest a solution?

Note: I'm sure this configuration worked perfectly until recently.

EDIT: 
The Samba configuration of the remote machine:

```
[root]
    comment = file system root
    path = /
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = otto

[otto]
    path = /home/otto
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = otto
    comment = otto's Home
```

Comment: Try to force a user with the option "force user = root"

Comment: I don't know where to add this option, but the user is defined in the .smbcredentials file.

Comment: You should add it where the other mount options "auto,users,...". That the user gets access to the share doesent mean that he will be able to do anything in the root folder of the remote computer, which typically can only be accessed by the root user. Forcing that user at mount type could prove therefore useful.

Comment: @EduardoLópez I am not trying to 'do anything' in the root folder, only list it and any user is allowed to do that. Anyway the user 'root' does not exist on either system.

Comment: Ok, so just do a simple test. In your pc, with your current user, try to access the root folder (cd /root). In my case, I get a nice "access denied" message. Thus, not every user can list its contents, just the root user, which by the way DOES exist in any Linux installation, despite Ubuntu has made this choice for security reasons to unable the use of the root account to log into the computer, both locally and remotely (in order to use the root user, just type "sudo -i" in a terminal window).

Comment: I think there has been a misunderstanding. My problem is not with '/root' but with '/' - the root of the file system.

Comment: Yes, your are right. But that makes no difference from a permissions point of view.

Comment: As the Germans say, doch! The '/' folder has read access for 'others', the '/root' folder not.

Answer (score 1):

Following this post:

[I want to share my "/" in samba. How to make it editable in windows networking?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60566/i-want-to-share-my-in-samba-how-to-make-it-editable-in-windows-networking)

> By default, your Samba users are not going to have write access to the
>   filesystem root. The easiest way to do this is to force a user. (Samba
>   users will access the share using the local user's privileges.) Make
>   sure that the user you specify has ownership and/or appropriate file
>   system permissions. For ease of use in my example, I'm using root.

```
[root$]
path = /
create mask = 0755
force user = root
browsable = yes
```

Also, be aware that certain default samba configurations include this line:

```
invalid users = root
```

Which you should remove if you REALLY want to access the remote's system root folder, which I personally discourage for security reasons. I'd rather recommend accessing the remote file system with SSH or even with [Gigolo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gigolo/) (SSHFS).

**EDIT**

I'm able to access (read-only) the root folder of another computer with this share configuration:

```
[Root]
   comment = Root
   path = /
   guest ok = no
   browseable = yes
   public = yes
```

So if you are not interested in having write permissions, just use that instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer has not addressed my question. I do not want write access to the filesystem root, I just want to list its contents.

Comment: The point is that you need permissions even to just list its contents...

Comment: Or at least make the share browsable (browsable = yes) or public (public = yes) in your share configuration. Sure thing is, that with your current configuration you get "access denied" and you have to change something accordingly, which is not gonna happen if you just stay there complaining and doing nothing. By the way, could you post the share configuration for your root folder?

Comment: I am most grateful for your help. I'll put the Samba configuration in the question above.

Comment: Na, endlich! ;-)

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Hmm? I was hoping the last posted config would.

Comment: Otto, did that work or not?

Comment: Did what work? You haven't suggested anything.Do you see anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Look at my last edit... did you try that configuration for your share?